# Writing to Request object in middleware

Tags: node.js

Is Request object thread-safe in node.js?

I'd like to overwrite parameter name having value "Sam" in Request object during middleware execution in router:

request from first user

```
App.use("/*", function(req,res,next){
   req.name="Bob"       
});
```

simultaneous request from another user

```
App.use("/*", function(req,res,next){
     req.name="Jack"       
});
```

In this simultaneous execution, is there possibility of second call overwrite value that was already started executing in the first call, or thread-safety of Request object guranteed?

Comment: what framework are you using? express? koa?  Either way each http request should have its own instance of the req object on the server. Are you finding that tnot to be the case?

Comment: I am using Express. I haven't tested it yet, what would be the correct way for testing this simultaneous requests?

Comment: its been too long since I coded express apps.  But i don't konw if i would be writing automated tests that ensure the functionality.  BUT if i was trying to prove this to myself, I might introduce a timeout in the API call and return the req.name in the response body.  Call separate multiple times  (bob and Jack) separated by some period of time less than the timeout.  They should both be through the middleware but blocked by the timeout.  If it was shared state the first should be overwritten by the second and only have one output.

Comment: that said - express is setup so each request has its own instance of the req object.  I'd be shocked if they changed that.  I can't even imagine how you would build a concurrnet web server with that model.